# Why does the output screen immediately close even after getch is used?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int x=0,y=0,z=0;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    z=x/2;
    for(y=2; y<=z; y++)
    {
        if(x%y==0)
        {
            printf("%d is not prime", x);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(y==z+1)
    { 
        printf("%d is prime", x);
    }

    getch();

}
```

Simple program to find a prime number, a school project, the code should work just fine but after making a .exe file through cmd using MWGin, the executable program closes soon after entering the number even though getch is implemented.

P.S- Ignore conio, its required in school.

Edit:- Solved now.

Comment: What's left in the input buffer after `scanf("%d, &x");`? (*hint:* `'\n'`) Wonder if `getch()` takes that as your input.... (avoid `getch()` it is 100% non-portable to anything other than DOS/windows -- `getchar()` works fine) Your biggest issue is you should do `char buf[1024]; printf("Enter a number:"); if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { return 1; } if (sscanf (buf, "%d, &x") != 1)) { return 1; } ...` That way you read a line at a time (including the trailing `'\n'`) and don't have to worry about what `scanf()` leaves in the input buffer....

Comment: Note: that should be `if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &x) != 1)` -- you have a quote in the wrong place. Hold on and I'll add an answer.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for `scanf` at all here.  Reading parameters from stdin instead of from command line parameters is a horrible anti-pattern when learning the language.  Reading input is hard to get right, and there's no need for the extra confusion.  Instead of reading `x` from the input stream, you ought to parse `argv[1]` (where main has been defined as `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  And don't ever write `void main() { ... }`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am barely a beginner so the answer seems more than a little confusing to me, but the problem seems to be because of the textbook I follow, I will look up new ones to correct whatever I was doing wrong. If you have any suggestions please list them, so.

Comment: If your textbook tells you to use `void main()` and `#include <conio.h>`, definitely get a better one. Try https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/modern-c/

Comment: @AdyanshMishra I am suggesting you do something like `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int x = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 10; ...`  and invoke the function with the parameter passed as the first argument.  Reading from `stdin` is unnecessary, and doing so with `scanf` is going to cause needless confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is when you use `scanf()` to read an integer from `stdin`, you also input `'\n'` as a result of pressing <kbd>[Enter]</kbd>. `scanf()` using the `"%d"` conversion specifier does not read the `'\n'` and leaves it in the input buffer (`stdin` here) waiting to be read by the next input. When `getch()` encounters the `'\n'` in the input buffer -- it takes that as your input and happily exits -- nothing to wait for.

This is one of many reasons why you should use `fgets()` for all user-input. `fgets()` will read an entire line of data (into a sufficiently sized buffer/character array) including the trailing `'\n'`. `scanf()` is so full of pitfalls for the new programmer -- just like this one, you should learn how to handle input in a way that what remains in the input buffer does not depend on the `scanf()` conversion specifier used or whether a matching-failure occurs.

`fgets()` is recommended for all new (and seasoned) programmers.

*How do I get my Number out from what `fgets()` reads?*

Answer: `sscanf()`. Simply parse the string filled by `fgets()` using `sscanf()` instead or attempting to read directly from the input stream with `scanf()`. There are many benefits to this approach, including solving the problem you have run into. Just pass your buffer as the first parameter to `sscanf()`. It's just like using `scanf()` from the conversion there on. Don't forget to VALIDATE every input and every conversion...

*What else is Wrong in Your Code?*

`void main()` is not defined for a standards conforming program. (it is an anachronism - a holdover from an ancient time) Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  *See*: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). *See also*: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)  In a freestanding environment, the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. *See*: [5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)

Space your code adequately. Errors are harder to find (and your old professor will go blind trying to read) code with all characters crammed together. The compiler doesn't care -- but humans do.

Lastly, always ensure you output a `'\n'` as the final output from your program to make your program POSIX compliant. Otherwise, it will mess up the command-line prompt for any user not using windows.

Putting it altogether,  you can do something similar to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (__MINGW32__)
#include <conio.h>
#endif

int main(void)
{
  char buf[1024];                 /* buffer to hold entire line of input */
  int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
  
  fputs ("Enter a number: ", stdout);
  
  /* read entire line of input into buf - validate EVERY input */
  if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* parse number from line using sscanf()  - validate EVERY conversion */
  if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &x) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid integer input '%s'.\n", buf);
    return 1;
  }
  
  z = x / 2;              /* WARNING - integer division! */
  
  for (y = 2; y <= z; y++) {
    if (x % y == 0) {
      printf ("%d is not prime\n", x);
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (y == z + 1) { 
    printf ("%d is prime\n", x);
  }

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (__MINGW32__)
  getch();
#endif
}
```

(note: the preprocessor macros just conditionaly include `conio.h` and call `getch()` if they are available -- otherwise they just skip that code)

Note the warning about *integer division* -- while intentional in this case, make sure you understand what it is. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the main problems with my code seem to be because of the textbook I am following which seems to be outdated by your answer, if you don't mind, could you recommend a textbook to study C from the beginning?

Comment: @AdyanshMishra - Happy to. Just drop by [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the scanf() function.

You wrote it:

```
scanf("%d, &x");
```

That's wrong. The variable "x"'s address, which will store the user input, is separate argument, it should be outside the string argument. Like this:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Then your program works.

I guess it's just a typo mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, corrected it based on the previous answers of /n buffer. Still, thanks